# Shift list elements to the right and shift list element at the end to the beginning

Tags: python

I want to rotate elements in a list, e.g. - shift the list elements to the right so `['a','b','c','d']` would become `['d','a','b','c']`, or `[1,2,3]` becomes `[3,1,2]`.

I tried the following, but it's not working:

```
def shift(aList):
    n = len(aList)
    for i in range(len(aList)):
        if aList[i] != aList[n-1]:
            aList[i] = aList[i+1]
             return aList
         elif aList[i] == aList[i-1]:
            aList[i] = aList[0]
            return aList
shift(aList=[1,2,3])
```

Comment: Im trying to shift the elements to the right so ['a','b','c','d'] would change to ['d','a','b','c']

Comment: Ignoring all the temporary lists create you could simply: `a[:] = a[1:] + a[:1]` you can rotate an arbitrary amount (n) `a[:] = a[n:] + a[:n]`

Comment: mis copy - let me see if I find the one i ment

Answer (score 17):

You can use negative indices together with list concatenation:

```
def shift(seq, n=0):
    a = n % len(seq)
    return seq[-a:] + seq[:-a]
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are allergic to slice notation: `a.insert(0,a.pop())`

Usage:

```
In [15]: z=[1,2,3]

In [16]: z.insert(0,z.pop())

In [17]: z
Out[17]: [3, 1, 2]

In [18]: z.insert(0,z.pop())

In [19]: z
Out[19]: [2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are trying to shift the elements, use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html) [`rotate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate) method:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from collections import deque
a = deque([1, 2, 3, 4])
a.rotate()
print(a)
```

Result:

```
[2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: With the slice, you are reversing not shifting.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: I know, but the question was unclear so I as unsure if he wanted to shift it or reverse it

Answer (score 7):

You can use this:

```
li=li[-1:]+li[:-1]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just slice the last element off the list, then add it to the beginning of a new list:

```
aList = [aList[-1]] + aList[:-1]
```

Here is the result:

```
>>> aList = [1,2,3]
>>> aList = [aList[-1]] + aList[:-1]
>>> aList
[3, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want to shift the elements, you can use modulo to cycle the list and reassign the elements to their shifted positions:

```
def shift(lst, shft=0):
    ln = len(lst)
    for i, ele in enumerate(lst[:]):
        lst[(i + shft) % ln] = ele
    return lst

In [3]: shift( ['a','b','c','d'] , 1)
Out[3]: ['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']

In [4]: shift( ['a','b','c','d'] , 2)
Out[4]: ['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']

In [5]: shift( ['a','b','c','d'] , 3)
Out[5]: ['b', 'c', 'd', 'a']
```

If you only want a single shift just shift the last element to the front extending the list:

```
def shift(lst):
    lst[0:1] = [lst.pop(),lst[0]]
    return lst
```

Both of which change the original list.

Answer (score 3):

The question seems to imply to me that the list itself should be modified rather than a new list created. A simple **in place** algorithm is therefore:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

e1 = lst[-1]
for i, e2 in enumerate(lst):
    lst[i], e1 = e1, e2

print(lst)
```

Giving:

```
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple use of slice syntax:

```
def shift(seq):
    return [seq[-1]] + seq[:-1]

assert shift([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Generalized version with changeable shift:

```
def shift(seq, shift=1):
    return seq[-shift:] + seq[:-shift]

assert shift([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == [5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
assert shift([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2) == [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function assuming `n` is the shift that is less than the length of list `l` like so:

```
shift = lambda l, n: l[-n:] + l[:-n] # i.e. shift([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done simply by using list method: insert,

```
values = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]

def shift(list):
    new_list = []

    for i in list:
        new_list.insert(len(new_list)-1, i)

    return new_list
```

print(shift(values))

Output is:

```
[3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your query :

```
def shift(aList):
    l = list()
    n = len(aList)
    l.append(aList[-1])
    temp = aList[:n-1]
    for i in temp:
        l.append(i)
    return l
print(shift(aList=[1,2,3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use *[roll](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html?highlight=roll#numpy.roll)* function from *numpy*.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> q = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> np.roll(q, 2)
array([4, 5, 1, 2, 3])
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

shift right and shift left functions:

```
def left_shift(seq, n=0):
    a = n % len(seq)
    return seq[1:] + [seq[0]]

def right_shift(seq, n=0):
    a = n % len(seq)
    return seq[-a:] + seq[:-a]

seq=right_shift(seq,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing with '+'

For left shift

```
def left_shift(seq):
    return seq[1:]+[seq[0]]
```

For Right shift

```
def right_shift(seq):
    return seq[-1:]+seq[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple elements in a list you can use this recursive method

```
def recurcieveShift(seq, n = 0):
    if n == 0:
        return seq
    seq.insert(0,seq.pop())
    recurcieveShift(seq, n - 1)
    return seq
```

I don't know what the space and time complexity hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
shift_by = 3
shift = 0
def rotate(l,shift_by, shift):
    '''Program shifts list elements by given
       number of times(shift_by) towards right or 
       left based on shift value given(shift = 0 means right shift;
       shift = 1 means left shift) '''
    x= list()
    for i in range(shift_by):
        if i>0:
            l = x
        if shift==0:#right shift
            a, *b = l
            x = b+[a]
        elif shift==1:#left shift
            *a, b = l
            x = [b]+a
    return x
print(rotate(l, shift_by, shift))
```