# Move all elements to right/left/let user choose (python)

Tags: python

I want to let the user choose either to move elements in an rng list either to the left, right or let them choose. I saw a similar post, but after reading it I did not see a way to choose which direction and do multiple repeats of the process.

```
import random

randlist = []

for i in range(10):
    randlist.append(random.randint(0,10))


x = input("Right? Left? Choose?")


if x == "Right":
    #Move all elements to the right once
elif x == "Left":
    #Move all elements to the left once
else:
    #Let User input both direction and amount of moves to the specified side
```

Comment: What do you mean "move"?  Rotate the 10 numbers left or right?  Give examples to clarify your question.

Comment: If the list was [1, 2, 3, 4], I want the list to be [4, 1, 2, 3] afterwards, and reverse for left. And if the user wants 3 times to the right, then the list would fo from [1, 2, 3, 4], to [2, 3, 4, 1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shift list elements to the right and shift list element at the end to the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498418/shift-list-elements-to-the-right-and-shift-list-element-at-the-end-to-the-beginn)

Answer (score 0):

Slicing the array helps here. Only when rotating more than the
length of array needs to be taken care. if lenght of array is
10 then rotaing 13 times is same as rotaing 3 times.

Code:

```
import random

def rotate_right(arr, n):
    m = n % len(arr)
    m = len(arr) - m
    return arr[m:] + arr[0:m]

def rotate_left(arr, n):
    n = n % len(arr)
    return arr[n:] + arr[0:n]
    
randlist = []

for i in range(10):
    randlist.append(random.randint(0, 10))
print(randlist)

print(rotate_right(randlist,13))
print(rotate_left(randlist,14))

x = input("Right? Left? Choose?")


if x == "Right":
    print(rotate_right(randlist,1))
elif x == "Left":
    print(rotate_left(randlist,1))
```

Output:

```
[0, 7, 3, 3, 0, 4, 0, 6, 6, 3]
[6, 6, 3, 0, 7, 3, 3, 0, 4, 0]
[0, 4, 0, 6, 6, 3, 0, 7, 3, 3]
Right? Left? Choose?
```