# Turn list clockwise for one time

Tags: python

How I can rotate list clockwise one time? I have some temporary solution, but I'm sure there is a better way to do it.

I want to get from this

```
  Index:     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
  Count:     0  2  4  4  5  6  6  7  7  7
```

to this:

```
   Index:     0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   Count:     0 0 2 4 4 5 6 6 7 7
```

And my temporary "solution" is just:

```
temporary = [0, 2, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7]

test = [None] * len(temporary)
    test[0] = temporary[0]


    for index in range(1, len(temporary)):
        test[index] = temporary[index - 1]
```

Comment: what do you mean by rotate clockwise? where are the extra 0 and 7 coming from in the expected output? nice name btw

Comment: This is a shift not a rotation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shift list elements to the right and shift list element at the end to the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498418/shift-list-elements-to-the-right-and-shift-list-element-at-the-end-to-the-beginn)

Answer (score 1):

You might use `temporary.pop()` to discard the last item and `temporary.insert(0, 0)` to add `0` to the front.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively in one line:

```
temporary = [0] + temporary[:-1]
```